# bundle will not start when bouncy castle is imported

Tags: maven, osgi, bouncycastle, apache-karaf

I am trying to add bouncy castle as a service provider to my java product running on apache karaf. 
When I am trying to start the bundle which imports bouncy castle I get an error message

java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle mvn:com.xxx.yyy.zzz/docsservice/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/war in feature(s) server-docs-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle docs [245]: Unable to resolve 245.0: missing requirement [245.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider)(version>=1.51.0))
                at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:472)

In the pom file I imported the package org.bouncycastle.jce.provider and I added bouncycastle as a dependency. 
Also, i made all the changes described on this page,
http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/security.html, see below

1. I put provider jar in lib/ext
2. I Modified the etc/config.properties configuration file to add the following property
   org.apache.karaf.security.providers = xxx,yyy

org.apache.karaf.security.providers = org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

3. I provided access to the classes from those providers from the system bundle so that all bundles can access those. I did this by modifying the org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation property in the same configuration file:

org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = ...,org.bouncycastle*

4. On some forum I found another suggestion so I modified 
   *org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra = * in the config.properties as well and I added here packages exported from bouncycastle

Nonetheless I wasn't able to load the bundle successfully. I looked at all the bundles loaded by karaf and none of them was exporting bouncy castle package. 
What am I missing here? How can I make the bundles to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the package to the boot delegation you made it available like java.* packages. For these you do not need an Import-Package. So one way would be to remove the Import-Package for it in your bundle. You should rather explore though if you can work without boot delegation.

Please try to remove the boot delegation and add the package to

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra = org.bouncycastle.jce.provider
```

This adds the package to the packages the system bundle exports. It should then be wired to your bundle.

Comment: I already added org.bouncycastle.jce.provider to the packages.extra (see my number 4 above).
Removing the org.bouncycastle.jce.provider from the import section of the pom file solved my problem. Thanks!
I have one more question. I don't understand what you mean by "It should then be wired to your bundle". Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: When a bundle goes from installed to resolved state the OSGi framework wires the classloader of the bundle. All packages in Import-Package will be wired to a bundle that exports a matching package. Only if this is successful the bundle is useable.